# Flash drive doesn't automount

Tags: usb-drive

I have automount and automount-open parameters set up in org.gnome.desktop.media-handling.
Tried all USB ports, USB is FAT32 formatted. Mounting through the terminal works, also founded more comfortable way of mounting, using Disks window, but still automounting would be better.

Comment: I have the same problem most of the time. Sometime it works --- I am not able to debug this more. I have a bug open here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1241811

Comment: Do you mean to ask that even after enabling automount and automount-open, it does not automount?